# failed to compile cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap on iPhone

Tags: iphone

failed to compile cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap  on iPhone, it does not recognize textLabel property. Could you let me know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

textLabel is a new property for UITableViewCells as of iPhone OS 3.0.  Are you trying to compile against an older version of the SDK?

Comment: You can get the equivalent functionality under 2.2.1 by using cell.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap.